# SSMS Performance issues when connecting to Azure Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, performance, azure-sql-database, ssms

I experience really slow performance on SSMS (V 18) when connecting to an Azure database (as opposed to an on-premise database)

I get performance issues when using the Object Explorer -e.g. when opening a View definition or opening table Design view. Regular Query performance is not the issue.

Has anyone else experienced this?

What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your Azure database is hosted in the Azure cloud. You are connecting via port 1433 over the WWW. Things like the object explorer are heavy hits on network utilization and things like default timeouts etc. are going to be highly un-tuned to your situation. Some things you could do:

1. Fire up a VM in Azure, install SSMS, open the firewall ports and see if you experience a lot more performant SSMS features.
2. Validate, or improve your internet connection. Latency, down/up speed being highly important.
3. Lastly, as this is likely NOT your main issue, increase your tier level for the hosted database. Assuming this is a hosted database in Azure? The default tier is NOT very performant and if you have a lot of objects it's trying to pop into your object explorer, this could help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @maplemale answer - check whether your database connection is set to [Proxy or Redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259).

If you can open the 11000-11999 port range in your corporate network then you can benefit from a Redirect connection where your client connects directly to the VM hosting your database rather than being proxied by Azure.